# Cannot install from ansible-galaxy on an FC22 machine

Tags: python, ansible

Ansible is installed from github, as per ansible site's instructions, and appears to work OK. But galaxy fails thusly:

```
# ansible-galaxy -vvv install goozbach.epel
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Opened /home/alf/.ansible_galaxy
Validate TLS certificates: True
Connecting to galaxy_server: https://galaxy.ansible.com
Base API: https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v1
ERROR! Unexpected Exception: 'Galaxy' object has no attribute 'roles_paths'
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ansible/bin/ansible-galaxy", line 86, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli.run())
  File "/opt/ansible/lib/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 153, in run
    self.execute()
  File "/opt/ansible/lib/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 114, in execute
    fn()
  File "/opt/ansible/lib/ansible/cli/galaxy.py", line 394, in execute_install
    roles_left.append(GalaxyRole(self.galaxy, **role))
  File "/opt/ansible/lib/ansible/galaxy/role.py", line 70, in __init__
    for path in galaxy.roles_paths:
AttributeError: 'Galaxy' object has no attribute 'roles_paths'
```

Same setup works fine on a CentOS6 machine (the FC22 is my laptop). I suspect some installation gotchas (missing python libs or other), but have not found anything so far.

**Edit**:
I could get it to install by replacing, in /opt/ansible/lib/ansible/galaxy/role.py, line 70 and 77, galaxy.roles_paths with galaxy.options.roles_path - inspecting the galaxy object in pdb, the property roles_paths is indeed not there. Understanding why it should be so, though, is a different matter.

Comment: I wouldn't install from github. If you aren't careful you could easily wind up with known-broken code. I'd just use the system packages: `dnf install ansible`

Comment: Fair enough, however, I wanted to run an updated version - dnf gives me 1.9.x for FC22,  CentOS6 repos give me zilch. Besides - as mentioned - the same install on CentOS has no visible problems - and certainly not the one in OP.

Comment: Eh? Ansible 1.9.4 is in EPEL for CentOS 6 and 7.

Comment: You are right - my bad. I ran the yum query on an open server window - which just happened to be the lone CentOS5 of the lot.